# How to design inserting to an infinite array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, data-structures

#### Problem statement

Imagine we have an infinite array, where we store integers. When `n` elements are in the array, only `n` first cells are used, the rest is empty.

I'm trying to come up with a data structure / algorithm that is capable of:

- checking whether an element is stored
- inserting a new element if it is not already stored
- deleting an element if it is stored

Each operation has to be in `O(sqrt(n))`.

#### Approach 1

I've come across [this site](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/n3iakr$q2g$1@digitalmars.com), where the following algorithm was presented:

- The array is (virtually, imagine this) divided into subarrays. Their lengths are 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, etc. the last subarray is not a perfect square - it may not be filled entirely.
- Assumption that, when we consider those subarrays as sets - they're in increasing order. So all elements of a heap that is further to the right are greater than any element from heaps on their left.
- Each such subarray represents a binary heap. A max heap.
- Lookup: go to first indexes of heaps (so again 1, 4, 9, 16, ...) and go as long as you find the first heap with its  max (max is stored on those indexes) is greater than your number. Then check this subarray / heap.
- Insert: once you do the lookup, insert the element to the heap where is should be. When the heap is full - take the greatest element and insert it to the next heap. And so on.

Unfortunately, this solution is `O(sqrt(n) * log(n))`.

How to make it pure `O(sqrt(n))`?

#### Idea 2

Since all the operations require the lookup to be performed, I imagine that inserting and deleting would both be `O(1)`. Just a guess. And probably once inserting is done, deleting will be obvious.

#### Clarification

> What does the *infinite array* mean?

Basically, you can store any number of elements in it. It is infinite. However, there are two restrictions. First - one cell can only store one element. Second - when the array stores currently n elements, only n first cells can be used.

> What about the order?

It does not matter.

Comment: Since you haven't specified a language, it's not clear what you mean by 'array'. In C and Java arrays have a finite size specified at initialisation. I suggest refining the question to explain exactly what you mean by 'infinite array'. Would a binary tree qualify, for example?

Comment: Also it's not clear to me whether the contents are expected to be sorted, nor what you mean by 'insert' (in a C/Java array you can't 'insert', you can only modify a value by index)

Comment: I've just edited the question. Shortly - the size is *infinite*. You just use first n cells.

Comment: Well then, it can't be done. The first step of creating an array is to allocate memory for every cell. Unless you're OK imagining a computer where `malloc(infinity)` works...

Comment: @slim: Of course it can be done. You just need to reallocate when the array gets larger.

Comment: @Richard then it's not an array. It's something more complex. So what are OP's constraints?

Comment: @slim: "I'm trying to come up with a data structure / algorithm". By your logic, nothing that gets reallocated can be an array.

Comment: @Richard I'm trying to coach him into stating that what he wants is an arbitrarily resizeable (which is different from 'infinite') set (which is different from 'array'). I think that's probably what he wants. Then maybe there are further constraints on his requirements that mean something based on a tree or a hash aren't acceptable, e.g. 'the backing store must be a contiguous block of memory' or 'I don't want to use pointers' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a [bi-parental heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beap) (aka: BEAP)?

The heap maintains a height of `sqrt(n)`, which means that insert, find, and remove all run in `O(sqrt(n))` in the worst case.

These structures are described in Munro and Suwanda's 1980 paper [Implicit data structures for fast search and update](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(80)90037-9).

Comment: That's actually a worst-case bound.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks, Richard!

Answer (score 0):

Create a linked list to a set of `k` arrays which represent hash tables.

Per the idea of the first site, let the hash tables be sized to contain 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, ... elements.

The data structure therefore contains `N=k*(k+1)*(2*k+1)/6=O(k^3)` (this is the result of a well-known summation formula for adding squares) elements with `k` hash tables.

You can then successively search each hash table for elements. The hash check, insert, and delete operations all work in `O(1)` time (assuming separate chaining so that deletions can be handled gracefully), and, since `k<sqrt(N)` (less than the cubic root, actually), this fulfills the time requirements of your algorithm.

If a hash table is full, add an additional one to the linked list. If a hash table is empty, remove it from the list (add it back in if necessary later). List insertion/deletion is `O(1)` for a doubly-linked list, so this does not affect the time complexity.

Note that this improves on other answers which suggest a straight-out hash table because rehashing will not be required as the data structure grows.

Comment: "When n elements are in the array, only n first cells are used"

Comment: If you're already using hash tables, and since the scenario is theoretically infinite, why not just use one hash table and get `O(1)` overall complexity rather than `O(sqrt n)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think approach 1 works, I just think some of the math is wrong.

The number of sub arrays is not `O(sqrt(n))` it's [`O(cuberoot(n))`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20i%5E2,%20i%3D1%20to%20n)

So, you get `O(log(n)*n^(1/3)) = O( (log(n) / n^(1/6)) * n^(1/2) )` and since `lim(log(n) / n^(1/6)) = 0` we get `O( (log(n) / n^(1/6)) * n^(1/2) ) < O(sqrt(n))`

My CS is a bit rusty, so you'll have to double check this. Please let me know if I got this wrong.

Comment: I thought the problem with that approach is that since the subarrays are supposed to be kept such that the sets of elements in them are in increasing order in relation to one another, updating can potentially affect all of the subarrays, adding too much to the complexity of operations.

Comment: @גלעדברקן The elements in the subarrays are not in increasing order but in a heap, I think insertion and deletion from a heap takes `O(log(n))`, if the number of subarrays is `O(cuberoot(n))` and you insert and delete from each one of them you get `O(log(n)*n^(1/3))`

Comment: I didn't say the elements in the subarrays are in increasing order. I said that in the algorithm the OP linked to, the *sets* of elements, that is the subarrays in relation to one another are supposed to be in increasing order. Or did I misread that description?

Comment: @גלעדברקן you read correctly, but even if you go though every subarray the complexity is still low enough

Comment: How do you delete the element from the first subarray (size 1) and avoid the `n` operations required to shift everything?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that fulfilling all of your requirements is impossible for the simple fact that an array is a representation of elements ordered by index; and if you want to keep the first `n` elements referenced by the first `n` indexes, as you say, any deletion can potentially require re-indexing (that is shifting elements up the array) on the order of `O(n)` operations.

(That said, ignoring deletion, this was my earlier proposal: Since your array is infinite, perhaps you won't mind if I bend one of the rules a little. Think of your array as similar to memory addresses in a computer, then build a balanced binary tree, consigning a block of array elements for each node (I'm not too experienced with trees but I believe you'll need a block of four elements, two for children, one for the value, and one for the height). The elements reserved for the children will simply contain the starting indexes in the array for the children blocks (nodes). You will use `4n = O(n)` instead of strictly `n` space for the first `n` elements (bending your rule a little), and have orders of magnitude better complexity since the operations on a BST would be `O(log2 n)`. (Instead of assigning blocks of elements, node construction could also be done by dividing each array element into sections of bits, of which you would likely have enough of in a theoretically infinite scenario.)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are storing integers just make the array 4 billion ints wide. Then when you add an element increment the integer equal to the element by 1. You will be able to add, remove, checking for the element will take O(1) time. It's basically just a hash table without the hash.

Comment: What is the expense of rehashing the array when it exceeds 4 billion?

Comment: It will never need to be rehashed. Integers can only have a value of 4 billion max.

Comment: What about 64-bit integers?

Comment: The array is supposed to be infinite, but the size of an integer is finite. So you can actually store like 4 gigs of memory. And have one for each value. And the count of how many of that value you have.

Comment: Very incorrect. Unsigned _4-byte_ integers can only have a value of 4,294,967,295. But unsigned _8-byte_ integers have a maximum value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. Assuming an 8-bit machine, of course. Naturally, you can design custom integer data types to have much larger values, or exotic hardware.

Comment: 64 bit integers is is not feasible. I've actually done this with 24 bit colors. 16 megs wasn't that much memory for the system I was implementing, where time was super-critical.

Comment: @Tatarize: This isn't a question about feasibility. It's a question about algorithms. Also: there is no requirement that all of the memory be allocated up front.

Comment: Yup, it's about algorithms. There are no real computers, just pure, wonderful theory.

Comment: Well then I go ahead and make in infinite table. Though really Hilbert's Hotel thing does then become relevant.

Comment: 16 gigs of memory rather. for storing that table. My lookup table for the 24 bits cost like 256 megs of memory.